# How to remove space above and below the in-line block elements?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I can't seem to figure out how to remove space **above** and **below** my `inline block` elements as shown in the image.

P.S `line-height` doesn't remove the space.

Here is the CSS for all the elements.

```css
nav ul li {
font-size:16px;
display:inline-block;
padding:20px;
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Image: 
[image: SS]

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bL1j558/)

Comment: cannot see image. can you post a link to the image?

Comment: @ankitjain11 done.

Comment: @str doesn't work, see the image to understand the problem.

Comment: Create [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: As @str mentions, did you try remove the padding.

Comment: @ankitjain11 tried bro, btw padding has to do with within the block as per i know, the problem is the space above the below the block.

Comment: I guess you'd need to create a fiddle as @vucko said.

Comment: @Akshit, try to add li float: left;

Comment: its getting very confusing, now. Inline-block, alone is not resposible for vertical. Going by the picture, as far as I understand, vertical-align has nothing to do here. So, it is either the parent block, that is responsible for spacing or some margin in the element itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` has by default `margin` and `padding`, so reset it

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
  background: #00795f;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  /* 40px top and bottom, 0px left and right */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  background-color: #43a286;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
 /* padding: 0; you may need only the margin */
  margin: 0
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
nav ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
ul li:hover {
  background-color: #399077;
}
section {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <h1>Loving it more everyday</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Home </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> About </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Blog </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Shop </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Gallery </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Contact </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section>
    When you try your best, but you don't succeed. When you get what you want, but not what you need. When you feel so tired, but you can't sleep. Stuck in reverse. And the tears come streaming down your face. When you lose something you can't replace.When
    you love someone, but it goes to waste. Could it be worse? Lights will guide you home. And ignite your bones. And I will try to fix you. And high up above or down below. When you're too in love to let it go. But if you never try you'll never know.
    Just what you're worth. When you try your best, but you don't succeed. When you get what you want, but not what you need. When you feel so tired, but you can't sleep. Stuck in reverse. And the tears come streaming down your face. When you lose something
    you can't replace.When you love someone, but it goes to waste. Could it be worse? Lights will guide you home. And ignite your bones. And I will try to fix you. And high up above or down below. When you're too in love to let it go. But if you never
    try you'll never know. Just what you're worth
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks, ticked correct, I feel stupid for not knowing this. I don't know why people are mentioning "Float" and all, that is a way different concept.

Comment: How can I ping you mate(If you have no problem) to ask something related to learning Web development?